# Excel formula - script

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a task, where I have two worksheets. I have values in the first column of the first sheet, lets call this the list. I need to copy all the rows from the second worksheet to a newly created worksheet that has any of the given values of the list in the first column. There are multiple occurrences for every value in the second sheet's first column. Can someone help me, please? I'm afraid formulas won't work here.

First sheet:

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | text |
| 2345 | text |

second sheet:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 43534 | 53534 | 78678 |
| 1234 | 44565 | 4523 | 3443 |
| 1234 | 54456 | 277575 | 65655 |
| 8654 | 426 | 3433 | 10013 |
| 2345 | 87654 | 443 | 76565 |
| 2345 | 565756 | 25264 | 74435 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create a Report (Lookup with Match)

- The following is an intermediate, not so efficient solution. It will try to match each value in column `A` (`sCol`) of Source Worksheet against each value in column `A` (`lCol`) of Lookup Worksheet. If matched, the current cell (`sCell`) in Source Worksheet will be added (combined) into the Combined Range (`crg`). Finally, the entire rows of the matching cells (of the Combined Range) will be copied to the destination worksheet.
- It is assumed that the data (tables) in all worksheets start in cell `A1` and have one row of headers.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub createReport()
    
    ' Lookup
    Const lName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const lCol As Long = 1
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const sCol As Long = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim lrg As Range ' Lookup Range
    With wb.Worksheets(lName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(lCol)
        Set lrg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        'Debug.Print lrg.Address
    End With
    
    Dim crg As Range ' Combined Range
    Dim srg As Range ' Source Lookup Range
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set crg = .Cells(1) ' Headers
        'Debug.Print crg.Address
        Set srg = .Columns(sCol).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        'Debug.Print srg.Address
    End With
    
    Dim sCell As Range ' Current cell in Source Lookup Range
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(sCell.Value, lrg, 0)) Then
            Set crg = Union(crg, sCell)
            'Debug.Print crg.Address
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    Dim dCell As Range ' Destination First Cell (Range)
    Set dCell = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Range("A1")
    
    crg.EntireRow.Copy dCell

End Sub
```